# Inkscape SVGs are rendered incorrectly in Firefox

Tags: svg, firefox, inkscape

Markers in SVGs are not rendered on the GitHub website.
This happens only on the website, the Android app doesn't have the same problem.

[Markdown file with the problem](https://github.com/kitswas/git-for-all/blob/main/Chapters/chapter2.md)

[image: The offending SVG]

The SVG was created using Inkscape.

When I noticed the problem, I changed the file to an optimised SVG (File -> Save As -> Optimised SVG) but didn't observe any changes.

**Edit:** The situation is thornier than I initially assumed.
Firefox doesn't display the markers at all while Chrome and Edge show them in black. The images on *this page* appear differently on different browsers.
I manually edited the XML to colour the markers and ended up with this file. [image: New SVG].
But Inkscape doesn't show the red outlines on the markers.

**Edit:** This is *not* a GitHub problem as I had initially suspected but an Inkscape(+Firefox) one. Still unsure whether Firefox is responsible.

Comment: This should work in Firefox now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MDN says,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/marker-end#usage_notes) (Highlight mine)

> `<marker-ref>`
>
> This value is a reference to a `<marker>` element, which will be drawn at the final vertex. **If the reference is not valid, then no marker will be drawn.**

[image: SVG with coloured markers]

In this file, notice the attributes `fill="context-stroke"` and `stroke="context-stroke"` on the `<path>` in the `<marker>`s.

Removing them fixes the problem. Still haven't found a direct way to do this from Inkscape.

[image: SVG with coloured markers]

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

Because the browsers still do not support all SVG2 features, there is a better workaround in Inkscape to fix that issue:

- Select **Edit** > **Preferences**.
- From the tree on the left, select: **Input/Output** > **SVG export**
- Under "*SVG 2 to SVG 1.1*" check the two checkboxes to use the correct direction and colors (as shown in the screenshot below).

[image: Check the two checkboxes to correctly render direction and colors]

- Now save the SVG file as follows:

  - **File** > **Save as**.
  - Check the box: "**Export as SVG 1.1 per settings in Preferences dialog**"
- Now the markers should be rendered correctly in the browsers.

[image]

**Note for Windows users**:

For Windows users, you need an extra step in order to enable the "*Export as SVG 1.1 per settings in Preferences dialog*" option. To enable it:

- Select: **Edit** > **Preferences**.
- From the tree view select: **Interface** > **Windows**.
- Under "Desktop integration" enable the option "GTK open/save dialogs", as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Desktop integration]

---

**Old answer (but still relevant)**

This is a known issue (see [here](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/2545)). A workaround is to use the following extension to color the markers:

**Extensions** > **Modify Path** > **Color Markers…**

Comment: I thank you(upvote) for pointing out that the issue is known. That workaround didn't work for me.

Comment: Check the box: "Export as SVG 1.1 per settings in Preferenes dialog" - I am using Windows and do not have that checkbox.

Comment: @Kitswas: Updated for windows users.

Comment: That GTK window is nice (I'll be keeping it), but the other steps didn't solve the problem.